# Get Build Log from Jenkins Workflow script at runtime?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow

I'm writing a Groovy script for a build that needs to send and email with the build log in the message body. I was wondering if there was an easy way to read the current build output without having to pipe every step to a temporary file. This needs to happen while the build is still running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can get it also during build via the REST-API:

```
http(s)://<server-URL>/job/<job-Name>/lastBuild/consoleText
```

Comment: This should work, even though the jenkins master server performs some cookie-base authentication. My request gets redirected due to lack of proper authentication, but from the browser it works, so I'll accept the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am using this script to trigger email:

```
if (build.getLog().contains("FAILED")) 
{
  cancel = true;
}
else
{
  cancel = false;
}
```

You can find the available methods [here](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Build.html).